# Creating instance of OSGi service leads to NullPointerException in Eclipse Product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have exported a product which consists of multiple plugin projects but when I run the product, it wont create an instance of an OSGi service from another plugin and throws a null pointer exception. Both these plugins are not the main plugin and I have updated the build.properties file to include the OSGI-INF folder containing the service definition.

Comment: Is the `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` plugin included in the build? It is needed to start declarative services.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your reply, was very helpful. However, things are now a bit more weird. Remember my previous question about class not found exception. That problem is now solved after including org.eclipse.equinox.ds plugin but I still get the null pointer exception when running the product exe outside eclipse. In eclipse, now when I run it using 'Launch an Eclipse application', everything is fine!

Comment: And I get another error since I included the OSGI-INF folder in the build.properties file, i.e.

[SCR] Component definition XMLs not found in bundle .... The component header value is ....

Comment: Check the `Service-Component:` entry in the MANIFEST.MF matches the file in the OSGI-INF and that everything has ended up in the plugin in the build.

Comment: Hi Greg, yes the entries match. I mean everything is working fine in Eclipse. Even when I run it using 'Launch an Eclipse application', everything is fine. The problem is running it outside eclipse as an executable. I opened the jar files of my plugins in the exported directory of product and everything seems to be in place!

Comment: Ok so I was able to made it to work ... another guy from Munich had the same problem and he was able to solve it and posted the solution on eclipse dev forums a few years back. It seems folder names are case sensitive while building the product and the manifest file had a folder name OSGi instead of OSGI!